# Background color won't change based on an array string

Tags: javascript, css

so i'm trying to do a project i found in https://jsbeginners.com/hex-change-background-color-project/ where i have a button and when its clicked, it changes the color of the background accompanied with a hex code for the color. i've seen some solutions for it but i'm wondering why mine isn't working

Javascript:

```
const colors = ['#C78283;', '#B80C09;', '#6B2B06;', '#E5E7E6;', '#B7B5B3;', '#CBE896;', '#FFFFFC;', '#FF7F11;', '#FF1B1C;',
 '#493657;', '#CE7DA5;', '#BEE5BF;', '#DFF3E3;', '#FFD1BA;', '#EF233C;', '#FCAF58;', '#FF8C42;', '#F4B860;'];

 
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    span.innerText= colors[Math.floor(Math.random() *colors.length)];
    document.body.style.background.color = colors.values;
});
```

everything works including the span changing to a random hex code from the array except the background color, it doesn't change. can someone help?

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML code. Also, please make sure you post a [mre].

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to check why your code is not working?

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;` where `randomColor` is the one you chose randomly previously. Please do at least minimal research before posting here. Also, hex values don't contain those semi-colons. https://jsfiddle.net/q6o4nbj1/

Comment: `colors.values` is undefined, `colors` is an array of string which does not have a property called `values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues.

- There should not be any `;` in the color list.
- Setting background color with `colors.values` is incorrect. `colors` is an array. So you have to access it using the correct index
- The background should be set with `document.body.style.backgroundColor`

I have redefined the code by keeping the random color in a string and setting the same value to span content and background color.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const span = document.getElementById('hex');
const colors = ['#C78283', '#B80C09', '#6B2B06', '#E5E7E6', '#B7B5B3', '#CBE896', '#FFFFFC', '#FF7F11', '#FF1B1C',
  '#493657', '#CE7DA5', '#BEE5BF', '#DFF3E3', '#FFD1BA', '#EF233C', '#FCAF58', '#FF8C42', '#F4B860'];

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  span.innerText = color;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<span id="hex"></span>
```

Comment: that works thank you so much!

Comment: @notyouraveragecoder welcome. Please approve the anser if this works for you.